# Segmentation fault when passing a pointer into function

Tags: c

When a `char *` is passed into this function `example: x`:

```
char* operandType;
char* armRegister;
MY_STRUCT muckVar;

char* armConverter(char* instruction) {
    printf("\nA %s\n", instruction);
    if (!isdigit(instruction)) {
        if (instruction=="+"){
            operandType="ADD";
            return operandType;
        }
        else if (instruction=="-") {
            operandType="SUB";
            return operandType;

        }
        else  if (instruction=="=") {
            operandType="MOV";
            return operandType;

        }
        else {
            muckVar.muckVar1 = instruction;
            muckVar.currentCount++;
            return instruction;
        }

    }
    else if (isdigit(instruction)) {
        muckVar.muckVar1 = instruction;
                    armRegister = strcat("R",instruction); 
        muckVar.currentCount++;
                    return armRegister;

    }
}
```

A segmentation fault is returned. What is it that is causing this error? Could it be due to an invalid pointer being passed into the function?

Comment: "*Could it be due to an invalid pointer being passed into the function*". Could be. But impossible for us to tell with an incomplete code snippet. You haven't even shown how the function is called when it seg faults. Please provide a complete [mre]. Also, have you done basic debugging by running the program in a debugger? A debugger will tell you instantly the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault as well as allow you to examine the variables leading up to and at the point of the seg fault.

Comment: `isdigit(instruction)` Please review the [isdigit manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit). It requires an `int` parameter not a `char *`.

Comment: `if (instruction=="+")` That is not how to compare strings in C. Either use `strcmp` or do a character compare `instruction[0] == '+'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will cause a segfault:

```
strcat("R",instruction)
```

You can't write to string literals, and `strcat` writes to its first parameter.

This will cause a segfault too:

```
isdigit(instruction)
```

Here's what the C standard says about the functions from `<ctype.h>`, of which `isdigit` is one:

> In all cases the argument is an int, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is
> undefined.

`instruction` is a pointer, which in practice will never meet those requirements when implicitly converted to an `int`.